# Как грузить данные в clickhouse, если в файл разделитель |?

Tags: clickhouse

cat /home/dima/test_data_clickhouse/sw_hosts.csv |clickhouse-client --host=*** -u *** --password=**** --query="use adm;INSERT INTO sw_hosts FORMAT |" --multiquery

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /home/dima/test_data_clickhouse/sw_hosts.csv | clickhouse-client --host=* -u * --password=**** --format_csv_delimiter="|" --query="use adm; INSERT INTO sw_hosts FORMAT CSV"
```